# What is happening with locks in my database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, locking

I'm having some problems on my database. At any given time, I'm trying to execute an update with five records on my table, but this table is locked and I get a time out executing the query.

I realized that if I execute update in only four records, the statement run sucessfully. And when I try to update the five recods together, it doesn't work.

Example:

```
--ONLY LOCKS IF THE UPDATE IS IN ALL FIVE RECORDS. (any combination works fine)

UPDATE X SET STATUS = 1 WHERE ID IN (1,2,3,4,5) -- THIS LOCKS THE UPDATE!!

UPDATE X SET STATUS = 1 WHERE ID IN (2,3,4) -- THIS  DOESN'T LOCK AND RUN SUCESSFULLY!

UPDATE X SET STATUS = 1 WHERE ID IN (1,4,5) -- THIS  DOESN'T LOCK AND RUN SUCESSFULLY!

UPDATE X SET STATUS = 1 WHERE ID IN (1,2,3,5) -- THIS DOESN'T LOCK AND RUN SUCESSFULLY!
```

Does anyone have an idea to how I fix this situation?

**EDIT 1:**
My isolation level is Read Commited.

Comment: Is there a trigger running on `UPDATE`?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud  there's no trigger running on my database

Comment: Why do you think it should be locking?

Comment: @Andy My application is multi thread and some other thread must be catching the same record. But I've never seen this type of lock, because no record that caught alone, the update just locks if the five records are updateds.

Comment: Have you tried the WITH(NOLOCK) hint on the other thread?

Comment: Please post the execution plan of the blocking statement and one of the non-blocking statements. Maybe they are different. Also, please show us what pre-existing locks are taken (maybe using `EXEC sys.sp_lock`).

Comment: @user3056839 Not, but this should work.
But I want to understand why locks only if the group of five records are in the update

Comment: @user3056839 `NOLOCK` won't work with a DML statement like `UPDATE`.  The DB **MUST** lock the records to handle them.

Comment: @LucasAbilidebob Locking is totally normal and happens every time data is changed or read.  There are different types of locks with different behavior based on what the engine needs to do.  This may be due to lock escalation.  How big is your table?  You can also try using the `ROWLOCK` hint to force row-level locking.

Comment: @JNK I'm using NHibernate, so I would like to understand what kind of lock is being done to know what action to take. Can you tell me what kind of lock is this?

Comment: There are very long whitepapers written on this so I can't give you a good summary in a comment here.  Basically, when the DB locks a row, it sometimes ESCALATES the lock to a page or extent or table depending on how much of the object it locks.  It's more efficient to track one table lock than 2 million row locks.  If your table is small it may be escalating to a table lock when it gets to 5 rows.  The `ROWLOCK` hint forces row-level locking which is less efficient for large scale operations.

Comment: Here's a good place to start if you want to learn about it: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Also please do NOT put `NOLOCK` into production code.  There are a lot of issues with using that hint, not least of which if you are changing a record that is being read and you use `NOLOCK` the reader may get wrong data depending on the timing.

Comment: If you're choosing the appropriate isolation level, I'd really let the DB engine worry about the locking and not try to "help" it.  There have been a lot of changes over the years and lock hints usually do more harm than good as the engine improves.

Answer (score 1):

When I run sp_lock, I realized that two locks in my table: PAG and KEY.
Searching more about KEY LOCK, I created an index for the column on the where clause, and this solve my problem.

**EDIT:**
When I removed the where clause (without index) , it worked fine too.